# Issue w/ JSON for bodyParser

Tags: javascript, json, express, fetch-api, body-parser

I'm sending data in my React component via the Fetch API, and returning the result as JSON. When POSTED on my Express server, I use the jsonParser method from bodyParser to parse through the data, but insead I'm only getting back a empty object. I do not understand what's the issue with jsonParser, because if I use textParser, my data get sent fine.

Edit: When printing out the request (req) on the server, it is showing that nothing was received in the body. This only happens with jsonParser though, and not textParser.

Fetch:

```
fetch('./test',{
  method: 'POST',
  body: ["{'name':'Justin'}"]
})
.then((result) => {
      return result.json();
    })
.then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
.catch(function(error){
      //window.location = "./logout";
     console.log(error);
    });
```

Express:

```
app.use('/test', jsonParser, (req,res) =>{
   res.json(req.body);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to post the `{name: 'Justin'}` object, you'll want something like

```
fetch('test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({name: 'Justin'}),
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  })
})
```

The `body` parameter does not accept an array (which is what you were passing).

---

If you did mean to post an array, simply change the `body` value to

```
JSON.stringify([{name: 'Justin'}])
```